# Broken packages when installing VELES - Ubuntu

Tags: apt, system-installation, package-management

When install VELES from https://velesnet.ml/ , it couldn't install due to a broke package:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ wget -O - https://velesnet.ml/ubuntu-install.sh | bash -
--2015-11-23 22:42:14--  https://velesnet.ml/ubuntu-install.sh
Resolving velesnet.ml (velesnet.ml)... 52.16.38.191
Connecting to velesnet.ml (velesnet.ml)|52.16.38.191|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 554 [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

100%[===============================================================================================================================>] 554         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2015-11-23 22:42:15 (105 MB/s) - written to stdout [554/554]

Requesting sudo...
[sudo] password for alvas: 
Thanks
--2015-11-23 22:42:19--  https://velesnet.ml/apt/velesnet.ml.gpg.key
Resolving velesnet.ml (velesnet.ml)... 52.16.38.191
Connecting to velesnet.ml (velesnet.ml)|52.16.38.191|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1033 (1.0K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

100%[===============================================================================================================================>] 1,033       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2015-11-23 22:42:20 (179 MB/s) - written to stdout [1033/1033]

OK
deb [arch=amd64] https://velesnet.ml/apt trusty main
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease                             
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty InRelease                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources                         
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty Release                                     
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.4 kB]                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://download.mono-project.com wheezy InRelease                          
Ign http://releases.neubot.org  InRelease                                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/main amd64 Packages                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages                   
Hit http://releases.neubot.org  Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://download.mono-project.com wheezy/main amd64 Packages                
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://releases.neubot.org  Release                                        
Get:2 http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb InRelease [8,143 B]              
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:3 https://velesnet.ml trusty InRelease                                     
Hit http://download.mono-project.com wheezy/main i386 Packages                 
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/universe amd64 Packages                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://releases.neubot.org  Packages                                       
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/restricted amd64 Packages                   
Get:4 https://velesnet.ml trusty/main amd64 Packages                           
Ign http://www.openprinting.org lsb3.2 InRelease                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/main i386 Packages                          
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Get:5 http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages [69.0 kB]    
Get:6 https://velesnet.ml trusty/main Translation-en_US                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/universe i386 Packages                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://www.openprinting.org lsb3.2 Release.gpg                             
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/restricted i386 Packages                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://download.mono-project.com wheezy/main Translation-en_US             
Ign http://download.mono-project.com wheezy/main Translation-en                
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/main Translation-en                         
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games amd64 Packages               
Hit http://www.openprinting.org lsb3.2 Release                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign https://velesnet.ml trusty/main Translation-en_US                          
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/multiverse Translation-en                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign https://velesnet.ml trusty/main Translation-en                             
Get:7 http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps i386 Packages [69.9 kB]     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/restricted Translation-en                   
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [5,081 B]            
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [5,062 B]             
Hit http://www.openprinting.org lsb3.2/contrib amd64 Packages                  
Ign http://releases.neubot.org  Translation-en_US                              
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [2,974 B]           
Hit http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/universe Translation-en                     
Ign http://releases.neubot.org  Translation-en                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://www.openprinting.org lsb3.2/contrib i386 Packages                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games i386 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/main Translation-en_US                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/restricted Translation-en_US                
Ign http://ftp.uni-mainz.de trusty/universe Translation-en_US                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps Translation-en_US             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en               
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps Translation-en       
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games Translation-en_US   
Ign http://www.openprinting.org lsb3.2/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games Translation-en
Hit http://www.openprinting.org lsb3.2/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en
Fetched 191 kB in 5s (36.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-veles : Depends: ocl-icd-libopencl1 (>= 2.1.3-5) but 2.1.3-4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My Distro:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

**How do I resolve the broke package problem so that VELES can be successfully installed?**

My outputs from `apt-cache policy python3-veles ocl-icd-libopencl1`

```
alvas@ubi:~$ apt-cache policy python3-veles ocl-icd-libopencl1
python3-veles:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.0-beta1
  Version table:
     1.0.0-beta1 0
        500 https://velesnet.ml/apt/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
ocl-icd-libopencl1:
  Installed: 2.1.3-4
  Candidate: 2.1.3-5
  Version table:
     2.1.3-5 0
        500 https://velesnet.ml/apt/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.1.3-4 0
        500 http://ftp.uni-mainz.de/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy python3-veles ocl-icd-libopencl1`

Comment: Your problems with `wine` are a completely different problem. Ask a new question for this problem.

Comment: Try a `sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-libopencl1= 2.1.3-5`

Answer (score 2):

**Answer in progress**

The package `python3-veles` depends on `ocl-icd-libopencl1 (>= 2.1.3-5)`. This version isn't available for Trusty in the standard Ubuntu repositories.

The version in https://velesnet.ml/apt/ is blocked by another dependency problem.

Either you upgrade to Ubuntu Wily or you could also try to force the installation of this package.

---

To repair your package system, follow the next steps...

The installation script has created an entry in your `sources.list`. Remove this entry:

```
sudo sed -i '/velesnet\.ml/d' /etc/apt/sources.list`
```

and update the package information

```
sudo apt-get update
```